# I cannot change the language of my phone

Tags: language-setting, nokia-lumia-1520

I cannot change the language in my Nokia Lumia 1520, it has changed into French on its own from English and I can't even open the language page in settings.

It started by changing the language on its own to French every now and then but I was always able to change it back by opening the language page in settings. But for a week now I've been unable to open the language page, the option is grey out.

I've been looking for similar cases on the Internet to find a solution but I haven´t found this problem anywhere.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I solved my problem by removing my nano sim and inserting a different one. When I  turned on my phone, the language went back to English. Then, I inserted my own nano sim again and the language was still English.
Just in case it helps someone else.